# I Initialized my HDD to MBR? Can I recover the data ? (Note.. I just intialized, nothing else.)

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery, mbr, gpt

I had an HDD in my Laptop. I connected that HDD to some other laptop via USBtoSATA bridge and it dint show in My Computer. After trying for several times, I went to disk management, and as soon as it opened it said I need to initialize my disk.
I selected intialize in MBR and then it showed unallocated space for my 1 TB HDD. I immediately disconnected my HDD. 
My laptop is in service center and will be available after one week. If I attach my HDD back into my laptop, will it work the way it used to ?
Is my data lost ?

Comment: No;  It won't work like it used to;  You deleted the MBR information.  You will have to install the operating system again.  Use file recovery software of your choice to get your personal data.

Comment: My answer there can solve your problem the same.

Comment: Alright.. I will try and will update..

Comment: Have a look at [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)

Answer (score 0):

I've used data recovery successfully in the past when i either deleted partitions or created new ones in error on a disk.

Partitioning usually doesn't touch data at all.

I used GetDataBack NTFS but that was about 10 years ago.. other apps are probably cheaper or better now.

Comment: Thanks.. Is the folder structure maintained ?

Comment: If none of the data has been overwritten it will. You should also check if the tool supports it.